# Why am I getting an NSInternalInconsistencyException after my second UITableView search?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I understand that under the UITableViewDataSource protocol, I must provide the number of rows per section.  In my FMDB SQL enabled app, I am returning this value when user does a table search, but if the search is canceled and then performed anew, the previous row count is still there, but the new search with no text is 0, causing an inconsistency exception.  To try to remedy the problem, I'm caching the count value right before cancel, but, that gives me the opposite inconsistency.  Should this row count be explicitly reset to zero on cancel?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (self.isSearching){

        if(self.searchReset){
            self.searchReset = NO;
            NSLog(@"Search reset prev row count: %ld", (long)self.prevSearchRowCount);
            return self.prevSearchRowCount;
        }

        NSLog(@"Title Count From Match: %ld", (long)[self getTitleCountWhereTitleMatch]);
        return [self getTitleCountWhereTitleMatch];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Title Count %ld", (long)[self getTitleCount]);
        return [self getTitleCount];
    }

}

-(void)searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    NSLog(@"Cancel clicked or did end search");
    self.isSearching = NO;
    self.searchReset = YES;
    self.prevSearchRowCount = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];
    [self.searchTitles removeAllObjects];
}
```

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (14) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

Answer (score 0):

#### first:

Make sure searchDisplayController's delegate is setted.

```
///Init UISearchDisplayController
_mySearchDisplayController=[[UISearchDisplayController alloc]initWithSearchBar:_searchBar contentsController:self];
_mySearchDisplayController.delegate=self;
_mySearchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource=self;
_mySearchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate=self;
```

#### second:

Use `tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView` to tell if is in search mode.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ( tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView )
    {
        return _arrayFilteredAudioFiles.count;
    }
    else
    {
        return  _arrayAudioFiles.count  ;
    }
}
```

#### third:

When you update(insert or delete) the cells. make sure you data is update first before the tableview try to reload data.